flutter Cached Network Image: not showing images
Trying to replace working Image.network() with CachedNetworkImage():
Image.network(
  url,
  headers: {},
);

with:
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: url,
  placeholder: (context, url) => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
  httpHeaders: {},
);

But image not shown, displaying CircularProgressIndicator forever.
UPDATE:
Exception: Invalid Image data from the errorWidget


whats the URL of the image?

you can try iphone image url: https://www.apple.com/v/iphone/home/bu/images/overview/select/iphone_15_pro__bpnjhcrxofqu_large_2x.png

I guess, You are trying to use cached_network_image in flutter web. But it's not supported on web. Try to print the error inside errorWidget(). When you run the same code in android/ios it'll work fine. For more info on web images: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/web-images

Actually the error is on android 14 real device.

I tested this on Samsung s23 android 14 real device

Just print your error inside errorWidget() and add that error in your question.

Try adding the internet use permission in AndroidManifest.json. Sometimes that too causes issue to load network images.

Exception: Invalid Image data from the errorWidget.  Image.network() works so it should not be a permission issue.

This happen to IOS only, take a ready in this solution using singleton:
First add this package: flutter pub add cached_network_image.
Create this classe in your project:
class CustomCacheManager {
  static final CustomCacheManager _instance = CustomCacheManager._internal();

  factory CustomCacheManager() {
    return _instance;
  }

  CustomCacheManager._internal();

  CacheManager getCacheManager() {
    return CacheManager(
      Config(
        'customCacheKey',
        stalePeriod: const Duration(days: 7), 
        maxNrOfCacheObjects:
            100, 
      ),
    );
  }
}

and for implement:
    CachedNetworkImage(
      cacheManager:
          CustomCacheManager().getCacheManager(), // Use  Singleton

      imageUrl: widget.feedModel.feedPhoto,
      progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) =>
          CircularProgressIndicator(value: downloadProgress.progress),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
    ),

